# AngularJS filter by unique dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data in the following form:

```
[
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '2013-11-27'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo1',
        date: '2014-02-07'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo2',
        date: '2014-06-13'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo3',
        date: '2015-02-28'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo4',
        date: '2015-05-10'
    },
]
```

Using Angular I want to first display the unique years in a dropdownlist.
How can I create a filter to use on a `<option ng-repeat="item in items">` that makes the dropdownlist contain 2013, 2014 and 2015, with each year being displayed only once?

Secondly, when a user selects 2014 in the dropdownlist I want only the items in that year display, so in this example only "foo1" and "foo2".
How can I filter that, say, for a div? `<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: item.date == selectedyear></div>`

Native solutions are preferred.

JSfiddle of how I want it to look for the user, and if the user has selected "2014": http://jsfiddle.net/GTHvidsten/k8hj45Lt/

Comment: can you please show what you attempted? we can build on that solution

Comment: Edited the post to include a sample of what I want the users to see.

Comment: I understood what you want the users to see. What I don't understand is why you haven't even made an attempt at the question

Comment: I have made several attempts, but none have even remotely worked. I haven't found a single stock filter by googling or examples of filtering by dates, or how to display only the unique years. So I really have nothing to show for on what I've done because I haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: You could share the failed attempts man. What matters is that you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple way to do it. Link to  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/1298/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selYear">
        <option ng-repeat="year in years" >{{year}}</option>
      </select>
      <select ng-model="selDate">
        <option ng-repeat="obj in data | filter:selectDatesByYear">{{obj.date}} - {{obj.title}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data=[
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '2013-11-27'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo1',
        date: '2014-02-07'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo2',
        date: '2014-06-13'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo3',
        date: '2015-02-28'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo4',
        date: '2015-05-10'
    },
];
    $scope.years = [];
    $scope.selYear = "2013";
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
        if (this.indexOf(value.date.substring(0,4)) ==  -1)
          this.push(value.date.substring(0,4));
    }, $scope.years);

    $scope.selectDatesByYear =  function  (obj) {
        if (obj.date.substring(0,4) == $scope.selYear) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simpler solution. Because I ended up using this instead of the other one I accepted this as an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a custom filter.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = 
  [
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '2013-11-27'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo1',
        date: '2014-02-07'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo2',
        date: '2014-06-13'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo3',
        date: '2015-02-28'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo4',
        date: '2015-05-10'
    }
  ];
  
  // check if a item is already in items
  var isDuplicate = function(items, item) {
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      if(items[i] === item) return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  
  // get all years from array
  $scope.getYears = function(array) {
    var years = [];
    
    angular.forEach(array,function(value){
      var y = parseInt(value.date.substr(0, 4));
      
      if(!isDuplicate(years,y)) {
        years.push(y);
      }
    });
    
    return years;
  };
});

app.filter('onlyYear', function() {
  return function(items,selectedYear) {
    // if no year selected, return all items
    if(!angular.isNumber(selectedYear)) return items;

    // populate array
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      var year = item.date.substr(0, 4);
      if(year == selectedYear){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="year for year in getYears(items)" ng-model="selectedyear"></select>
    <div>selected year: {{selectedyear}}</div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | onlyYear:selectedyear">{{item.title}} ({{item.date}})</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** Using custom filter (with `$filter('date')`)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.items = 
  [
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '2013-11-27'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo1',
        date: '2014-02-07'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo2',
        date: '2014-06-13'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo3',
        date: '2015-02-28'
    },
    {
        title: 'foo4',
        date: '2015-05-10'
    }
  ];
  
  // check if a item is already in items
  var isDuplicate = function(items, item) {
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      if(items[i] === item) return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  
  // get all years from array
  $scope.getYears = function(array) {
    var years = [];
    
    angular.forEach(array,function(value){
      var y = $filter('date')(value.date,'yyyy');
      
      if(!isDuplicate(years,y)) {
        years.push(y);
      }
    });
    
    return years;
  };
});


app.filter('onlyYear', function($filter) {
  return function(items,selectedYear) {
 
    // if no year selected, return all items
    if(typeof selectedYear == 'undefined') return items;
    selectedYear = parseInt(selectedYear);

    // populate array
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      var year = $filter('date')(item.date,'yyyy');
  
      if(year == selectedYear){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="year for year in getYears(items)" ng-model="selectedyear"></select>
    <div>selected year: {{selectedyear}}</div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | onlyYear:selectedyear">{{item.title}} ({{item.date}})</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This isn't too far from what I'd already tried, but me being too newbie at Angular just couldn't get everything to place nice with eachother. Thanks!

Comment: I notice you use substr(ing) to parse the dates. In some google searches it does turn out that AngularJS has some built in date functionality (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). Is it possible to use this filter with how your code is implemented? Is it also possible to use the Date() class in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use both. I added the code using `$filter`, implemented in Angular.